# Trying to convert total minutes from a datediff to days, remaining hours, & minutes in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff

I am using Crystal Reports 2013 SP5 on Windows 7 Pro pulling from an Oracle db.

I am trying to write a formula(s) in crystal reports that returns the total number of days the remaining hours if less than 24, and the remaining minutes if less than 60 from a datediff between two date time fields.

So far I have managed to show the total number of minutes as days, hours, and minutes:

```
local numbervar tm := datediff('n',{table.date1},{table.date2},0);
local numbervar h := truncate(tm/60,0);
local numbervar d := truncate(tm/1440,0);

local stringvar tm_d := totext(d,0,"") + ' days ';
local stringvar tm_h := totext(h,0,"") + ' hours ';
local stringvar tm_m := totext(tm,0,"") + ' minutes ';

local stringvar tm_string := tm_d & tm_h & tm_m
```

Returns:  183 days 4393 hours 263633 minutes

183 days which is = to 4393 hours which is = to 263633 minutes

What I need it to do is show 183 days (not rounded) and any remaining hours (not rounded) and any remaining minutes (not rounded) so it looks something like this:

The difference between table.date1 and table.date2 is:

183 days 4 hours 23 minutes (just used random hours and minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this also.

```
local numbervar tt := datediff('n',{table.DATE1},{table.DATE2});
local numbervar d := truncate(tt/1440,0);
local numbervar h := truncate(remainder(tt,1440)/60,0);
local numbervar m := truncate(remainder(tt,60),0);
local stringvar tt_d := if d=0 then "" else totext(d,0,"") + 'd ';
local stringvar tt_h := if h = 0 then "" else (totext(h,0,"")) + 'h ';
local stringvar tt_m := totext(m,0,"") + 'm ';
local stringvar tt_string := tt_d & tt_h & tt_m
```

Refer links :

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=15879

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=10279

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting/Crystal_Reports/Q_24014196.html

Comment: OMG Ajay2707, that is it....!!!  I have added this to my example sheet and included the links you suggest.  Thank you very much for your help, the return is perfect!

Comment: If it is perfect, then accept the answer too. I give you +1 vote for your question as it is used day to day.

Answer (score 0):

Have no experience with your system, but definitely you'll need this:

```
totalMinutes = 263633 
days = floor (totalMinutes /(24*60))
hours  = floor (totalMinutes %(24 * 60) /(60))
minutes = floor (totalMinutes % 60)


where % is MOD (ex: 15 MOD 4 = 3)
```

as far as I see, `floor` is same as `truncate`, and quick lookup gave, that MOD is `MOD` like `A MOD B`

Comment: Thanks Nikita, I'm on my way home now but I'll try this in the morning.